# Clear specific item cache using MEMCACHE PHP

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I used to clear cash using flush() in PHP every day, like 5-10 times.
I want to clear specific items cache to prevent caching all server cache.
This is the right way:

1. Use Memcache::delete() to delete item
2. Memcache::add() the same item

Is it correct?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

But be aware that Memcache::add() will fail if the key already exists.
If you always want to write the data even though it exists already, you can use Memcache::set() instead.

Another a little bit funky thing with the memcache PHP class, is that TTL is measured in seconds, but if it is larger than 30 days it instead is interpreted as a date stamp (unix timestamp).